# ¿Como se abre el ejecutable de un programa en Java hecho por consola?

Tags: java

Cuando abro el ejecutable de un programa en Java que tiene interfaz gráfica no hay ningún problema, pero si el programa está hecho por consola no sale nada al abrir el ejecutable, ¿como puedo abrirlo? ¿se puede desde la linea de comandos de windows?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: primero tendrás que "compilarlo" con `javac archivo.java` y luego ejecutarlo con `java nombre_clase_que_contiene_main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde CMD debes ir al directorio del jar haciendo un CD,  una vez en el directorio debes escribir el siguiente comando.

java - jar Nombre archivo.jar